# Bilinear Interpolation on rasters to create daily raster files

Tags: python, r, raster, gdal

I have raster (.tif) files for every four days interval (e.g. LAI.Day.2015.10.24.tif, LAI.Day.2015.10.28.tif, LAI.Day.2015.11.01.tif, LAI.Day.2015.11.05.tif, LAI.Day.2015.11.09.tif, so on). Is there any way to get daily raster files (e.g. LAI.Day.2015.10.24.tif, LAI.Day.2015.10.25.tif, LAI.Day.2015.10.26.tif, so on) using bilinear interpolations on the raster files having temporal resolution of four days?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think *bilinear* interpolation applies to time as it applies to space. But you can interpolate. In R, you could use raster::calc with `approx`. See the regression example in calc.

Comment: I read a research paper where the authors write "To generate daily LAI fields , the 8-day composites were bi-linearly interpolated in time". Here is the link to the paper https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/2006JD007506. Please see section 3.2 of the paper. According to the paper, bi-linear interpolation can be done in time also.